# Does Bullwinkle visit each shul after davening each Monday morning?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[image: Bullwinkle the Moose]

At the end of every Monday morning davening, I hear the *chazan* say: "*Hu Yenahagenu al moose.*" - He will make us ride on a moose.

Does that mean that Bullwinkle visits the shul each Monday and everyone has to ride on him?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: how do you know it means bullwinkle and not some other moose?

Comment: @Yitzhak - it could be any moose, actually. It's just that Bullwinkle is recognizable.

Answer (score 4):

This is a machlokes between Sefardim and Ashkenazim.

Sefardim say this is an addition from the [Kaifeng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaifeng_Jews) community intended to recognize the leadership of [Hu Yaobang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hu_Yaobang) which some Chinese believe will continue to last until the Year of the Moose is introduced into their calendar in recognition of the 13th zodiac sign (because really [Ophiuchus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophiuchus_%28astrology%29) looks much more plausibly like moose horns than serpent parts).

Ashkenazim say that Hu is the international code for Hungarian, and this is saying that [Hungarian Chocolate Mousse Cake](http://thegourmetproject.blogspot.com/2009/01/hungarian-chocolate-mousse-cake-bars.html) is the proper way to prepare a Mousse.

[image: An Hungarian Chocolate Mousee Cake bar]

Comment: OMG - That cake looks soooo delicious. Who makes that and where can I buy it?